# How can I pass/get model data in my itemViewClass in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a template with code like:

```
{{# each p in controller itemViewClass="MyApp.SomeView" itemController="some" }}
  // some stuff
{{/each}}
```

In my itemViewClass:

MyApp.SomeView = Ember.View.Extend({

```
attributeBindings: ['foobar'],
foobar: function() {

    return this.get('stuff_from_the_model');

}
```

});

I've tried many variants on this. Using property(), using controller.model, and a host of others. It always seems to be empty. Is there a way I can pass values from the template into this view directly? Or is there some other way? The value I need is unique to each instance of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
attributeBindings: ['foobar'],
foobar: function() {

    return this.get('controller.model.stuff_from_the_model');

}.property()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `{{#each}}` with `itemController` and `itemView` bindings is just `{{#collection}}` ([Ember.js {{each}} vs {{collection}}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500250/ember-js-each-vs-collection)).

In `{{#each}}` helper itemView's role plays code in scope `{{#each}}<pseudo-item-view>{{/each}}`.
Look at an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yutaniyi/1/

Secondly, if there is need to bind to exactly one field (path) of controller/etc, then we might use `Em.computed.alias` for this task (see in example).